# tic tac toe game java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am very novice Java student, who was assigned a tic tac toe game.  When I try to compile and run the program, I get the following error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at tictactoegame.TicTacToeGame.displayBoard(TicTacToeGame.java:55)

at tictactoegame.TicTacToeGame.main(TicTacToeGame.java:23)

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I also get an warning in my createBoard method that says `"Local variable hides a field"`

Below is my code for the project so far.  Most of the code was provided to me by the school, and I am suppose to initialize the array in the createBoard method and determine the winner in the winOrTie method.   Would anyone have any ideas how to get this to run?  Am I doing something wrong in the initization of the array?  Thank you to anyone who can help me out with this.

```
package tictactoegame;

import static tictactoegame.TicTacToeGame.gameboard;

public class TicTacToeGame {

   static int[][] gameboard;
   static final int EMPTY = 0;
   static final int NOUGHT = -1;       //this is an 'O'
   static final int CROSS = 1;         //this is an 'X'

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      createBoard(3,3);
      int turn =0;
      int playerVal;
      int outcome;

      java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

      do {
         displayBoard();
         playerVal = (turn % 2 == 0)? NOUGHT : CROSS;
         if (playerVal == NOUGHT) System.out.println("\n--O's turn--");
         else System.out.println("\n--X's turn--");
         System.out.print("Enter row and column");

         try {
            set(playerVal, scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt());   
         } catch (Exception ex) {System.err.println(ex);}
         turn++;
         outcome = winOrTie();
      } while (outcome == -2);
      displayBoard();
      switch (outcome){
         case NOUGHT:
            System.out.println("O wins!");
            break;
         case CROSS:
            System.out.println("X wins!");
            break;
         case 0:
            System.out.println("Tie.");
            break;
      }
   }

   static void set(int val, int row, int col) throws
      IllegalArgumentException {
      if (gameboard[row][col] == EMPTY) gameboard[row][col] = val;
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Player already there!");
   }



   static void displayBoard() {
      for(int r=0; r < gameboard.length; r++) {
         System.out.print("|");
         for(int c=0; c < gameboard[r].length; c++) {
            switch(gameboard [r][c]) {
               case NOUGHT:
                  System.out.print("O");
                  break;
               case CROSS:
                  System.out.print("X");
                  break;
               default:            //Empty
                  System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print("|");

         }

         System.out.println("\n-----\n");            

      }

   }



   static void createBoard(int rows, int cols) {
      int gameboard[][]=  new int[3][3];
   }



   static int winOrTie() {           

      //NOUGHT wins horizontal

      if (gameboard[0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[0][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[0][2] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;
      else if (gameboard[1][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][2] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;
      else if (gameboard[2][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][2] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;

      //NOUGHT wins veritcal

      else if (gameboard[0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][0] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;
      else if (gameboard[0][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][1] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;
      else if (gameboard[0][2] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][2] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][2] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;

      //NOUGHT wins diagonal

      else if (gameboard[0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][2] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;
      else if (gameboard[0][2] == NOUGHT && gameboard[1][1] == NOUGHT && gameboard[2][0] == NOUGHT)
         return NOUGHT;

      //CROSS wins horizontal

      else if (gameboard[0][0] == CROSS && gameboard[0][1] == CROSS && gameboard[0][2] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;
      else if (gameboard[1][0] == CROSS && gameboard[1][1] == CROSS && gameboard[1][2] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;
      else if (gameboard[2][0] == CROSS && gameboard[2][1] == CROSS && gameboard[2][2] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;

      //CROSS wins veritcal

      else if (gameboard[0][0] == CROSS && gameboard[1][0] == CROSS && gameboard[2][0] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;
      else if (gameboard[0][1] == CROSS && gameboard[1][1] == CROSS && gameboard[2][1] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;
      else if (gameboard[0][2] == CROSS && gameboard[1][2] == CROSS && gameboard[2][2] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;

      //CROSS wins diagonal

      else if (gameboard [0][0] == CROSS && gameboard[1][1] == CROSS && gameboard[2][2] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;
      else if (gameboard [0][2] == CROSS && gameboard[1][1] == CROSS && gameboard[2][0] == CROSS)
         return CROSS;               
      else
         return -2;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a debugger.

Comment: Pay close attention to warnings provided by the compiler. Java is pretty good about only warning for good reason. In this instance it is pointing you directly at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your are shadowing the `gameboard` variable.  When you call `createBoard` you are creating a new, local variable and initialising it, this leaves your other `createBoard` variable uninitialised.

```
 static void createBoard(int rows, int cols) {
     int gameboard[][]=  new int[3][3];
 }
```

Try....

```
 static void createBoard(int rows, int cols) {
     gameboard =  new int[3][3];
 }
```

Instead

Comment: Well that solved one issue but brought about another issue although.  Now I got an error on these lines saying ';' expected Not a statement ']'expected not a statement.  Any idea about that??  Thanks for your help.